# MySQL find the first of each "group"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains data that are in ascending order in Col2, Col3 and descending in Col4. So an example table is the following:

```
    +------+------+------+------+
    | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
    +------+------+------+------+
    |  11  |   a  |   b  |   1  |
    +------+------+------+------+
    |  21  |   a  |   b  |   0  |
    +------+------+------+------+
    |  31  |   d  |   c  |   0  |
    +------+------+------+------+
    |  41  |   a  |   e  |   0  |
    +------+------+------+------+
    |  22  |   f  |   a  |   1  |
    +------+------+------+------+
    |  23  |   f  |   a  |   0  |
    +------+------+------+------+
```

The result I want to accomplish is to get the data that have no duplicates in Col2 and Col3 as is and also from those who have duplicates only retrieve the ones with "1" in Col4. So using the above table the result should be:

```
    +------+------+------+------+
    | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
    +------+------+------+------+
    |  11  |   a  |   b  |   1  |
    +------+------+------+------+
    |  31  |   d  |   c  |   0  |
    +------+------+------+------+
    |  41  |   a  |   e  |   0  |
    +------+------+------+------+
    |  22  |   f  |   a  |   1  |
    +------+------+------+------+
```

Is this possible in MySQL?

Comment: Seems perfectly possible. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query using `GROUP BY` with `MIN()` and `MAX()` appears to produce the wanted result.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`Col1` int, `Col2` varchar(1), `Col3` varchar(1), `Col4` int);
>
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`, `Col4`)
> VALUES
>     (11, 'a', 'b', 1),
>     (21, 'a', 'b', 0),
>     (31, 'd', 'c', 0),
>     (41, 'a', 'e', 0),
>     (22, 'f', 'a', 1),
>     (23, 'f', 'a', 0);
> ```

> ```
> select min(`Col1`) Col1, `Col2`, `Col3`, max(`Col4`)
> from Table1
> group by `Col2`, `Col3`
> order by `Col2`, `Col3`;
> ```
>
> ```
> Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | max(`Col4`)
> ---: | :--- | :--- | ----------:
>   11 | a    | b    |           1
>   41 | a    | e    |           0
>   31 | d    | c    |           0
>   22 | f    | a    |           1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=329e364a5cf1424122d8d73e49036541)*